# How do I convert a Color to a Brush in XAML?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml, colors, converters

I want to convert a System.Windows.Media.Color value to a System.Windows.Media.Brush. The color value is databound to a Rectangle object's Fill property. The Fill property takes a Brush object, so I need an IValueConverter object to perform the conversion.

Is there a built-in converter in WPF or do I need to create my own? How do I go about creating my own if it becomes necessary?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372693/convert-string-to-brushes-brush-name-in-c

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. I want to convert from a Color object, not a string value like "Red." And I'd like to implement it as a XAML converter, vs. performing the conversion in C# code behind.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It seems that you have to create your own converter. Here a simple example to start:

```cs
public class ColorToSolidColorBrushValueConverter : IValueConverter {

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        if (null == value) {
            return null;
        }
        // For a more sophisticated converter, check also the targetType and react accordingly..
        if (value is Color) {
            Color color = (Color)value;
            return new SolidColorBrush(color);
        }
        // You can support here more source types if you wish
        // For the example I throw an exception

        Type type = value.GetType();
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported type ["+type.Name+"]");            
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        // If necessary, here you can convert back. Check if which brush it is (if its one),
        // get its Color-value and return it.

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use it, declare it in the resource-section.

```
<local:ColorToSolidColorBrushValueConverter  x:Key="ColorToSolidColorBrush_ValueConverter"/>
```

And the use it in the binding as a static resource:

```
Fill="{Binding Path=xyz,Converter={StaticResource ColorToSolidColorBrush_ValueConverter}}"
```

I have not tested it. Make a comment if its not working.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Chris Valentine.  Even though Jens' answer has great elegance, in my case I was not able to use it and I had to use the Converter.  Or perhaps I could not see how to implement SolidColorBrush in my case.

Answer (score 159):

I know I am really late to the party, but you don't need a converter for this.

You could do

```
<Rectangle>
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding YourColorProperty}" />
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: This solution is much better than the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Though I like this solution, it does indeed result in annoying warnings as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926204/cannot-find-governing-frameworkelement-warning-when-binding-inside-datatemp

Comment: If you're confused about what `YourColorProperty` is like I was, it's most likely a property that is viewable from the current XAML scope in your C# code-behind.

Answer (score 15):

A `Converter` is not needed here. You can define a `Brush` in `XAML` and use it. It would be better to define the `Brush` as a `Resource` so it can be used other places required.

`XAML` is as below:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding ColorProperty}" x:Key="ColorBrush" />
</Window.Resources>
<Rectangle Width="200" Height="200" Fill="{StaticResource ColorBrush}" />
```

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to do this HCL's way rather than Jens' way because I have a lot of things bound to the `Color`, so there's less duplication and boiler-plate `.Fill` nodes.

However when trying to write it, ReSharper pointed me to the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/)'s implementation of the ColorToSolidColorBrushConverter. You need to include the following namespace declaration in the main Window/UserControl node:

```
xmlns:Toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Core.Converters;assembly=WPFToolkit.Extended"
```

Then a static resource in the Window/UserControl resources:

```
<Toolkit:ColorToSolidColorBrushConverter x:Key="colorToSolidColorBrushConverter" />
```

Then you can do it like HCL's answer:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding Color, Converter={StaticResource colorToSolidColorBrushConverter}}" />
```

Answer (score 4):

With some more enhancment to HCL answer, I tested it - it works.

```
public class ColorToSolidColorBrushValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        if (value is Color)
            return new SolidColorBrush((Color)value);

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported type [" + value.GetType().Name + "], ColorToSolidColorBrushValueConverter.Convert()");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        if (value is SolidColorBrush)
            return ((SolidColorBrush)value).Color;

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported type [" + value.GetType().Name + "], ColorToSolidColorBrushValueConverter.ConvertBack()");
    }

}
```

Comment: After posting it.. I noticed Jens answer.. which is accurate :)

Answer (score 1):

Converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(Color))]
public class SolidBrushToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is SolidColorBrush)) return null;
        var result = (SolidColorBrush)value;
        return result.Color;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
//...
<converters:SolidBrushToColorConverter x:Key="SolidToColorConverter" />
//...
<Color>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource YourSolidColorBrush}"
             Converter="{StaticResource SolidToColorConverter}">
    </Binding>
</Color>
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to HCLs answer: If you don't want to care if System.Windows.Media.Color is used or System.Drawing.Color you can use this converter, which accepts both:

```
public class ColorToSolidColorBrushValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case null:
                return null;
            case System.Windows.Media.Color color:
                return new SolidColorBrush(color);
            case System.Drawing.Color sdColor:
                return new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(sdColor.A, sdColor.R, sdColor.G, sdColor.B));
        }

        Type type = value.GetType();
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported type [" + type.Name + "]");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching) there's no need for neither null checking and double casting:

```cs
public class ColorToSolidBrushValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Color color) return new SolidColorBrush(color);

        throw new InvalidOperationException(nameof(color));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Optional implementation for **ConvertBack**:

```cs
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value is SolidColorBrush brush)
    {
        return brush.Color;
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException(nameof(brush));
}
```