# How can i create a Point Object in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, wpf-controls, custom-controls

there is a Line control which we can define like this:

```
<Line X1="10" Y1="30" X2="100" Y2="100" Stroke="Red" />
```

I'd like to create a point object of which i could define like this

```
<my:Point X="12" Y="44" Fill="Red" />
```

the whole point of this is that i could avoid calling Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left methods
anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a `Point` class in the namespace referred to by the XML namespace `my`, and it has settable properties named `X`, `Y` and `Fill` of a compatible type, then instantiating an object in XAML is as simple as your example.

Of course you may need to [convert from the string `"Red"` to a `Brush`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3309709/50079), but that's easy.

The more interesting question is *how exactly do you want to use that object*?