# Binding Style Setter to a public property?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I want to bind the `Fill` property in a style to a public property, I've used the following way but it seems like it doesn't work.

```
public SevenSegmentControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SevenSegmentColor = Color.FromRgb(251, 23, 23);
}

public Color SevenSegmentColor { get; set; }
```

```
<Style x:Key="RectangleStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{Binding Path=SevenSegmentColor, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Setter Property="RadiusX" Value="4"/>
    <Setter Property="RadiusY" Value="4"/>
    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
</Style>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Please describe "doesn't work"

Comment: I mean, `Fill` attribute doesn't show and the rectangle shows as transparent.

Comment: Your binding is broken, otherwise it would have thrown an exception since you cannot bind a brush-property to a color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set a color value directly to the [Fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.fill.aspx) property,which is of type Brush.You can inspect the Output window to find out the [binding errors](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=52).Either you need a [valueconverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309709/how-do-i-convert-a-color-to-a-brush-in-xaml/3309904#3309904) to convert your color to a valid brush or you need to do like this

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SevenSegmentColor =new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(251, 23, 23));
            DataContext=this;
        }

        public SolidColorBrush SevenSegmentColor { get; set; }

    }
```

**EDIT**

If you are assigning the Datacontext before the Property value is set,the UI will never be notified in your Property change.As in your case you are assigning the datacontext using

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

So the Datacontext is set at the initialization time itself before your `SevenSegmentColor` property is assigned a value.Later after initialization when you assigned a color value to your Property, the UI will never get notified and hence your color is not shown in the UI.To solve this you need to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) Interface in your UserControl

**Sample**

```
 /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private SolidColorBrush sevenSegmentColor;
        public MainWindow()
        { 
            InitializeComponent();
           SevenSegmentColor =new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(251, 23, 23));
        }

        public SolidColorBrush SevenSegmentColor
        {
            get
            {
                return sevenSegmentColor;
            }
            set
            {
                sevenSegmentColor = value;
                // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
                OnPropertyChanged("SevenSegmentColor");
            }
        }

        // Declare the event
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've done it, but the problem doesn't solve and the rectangle doesn't show any colors again !!!!

Comment: Are you sure you have set the datacontext..? Have you checked the output window for binding errors..?

Comment: I've added `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` for DataContext, Also I checked the output window, no error no faild !!!

Comment: BTW: the project is an UserControl

Comment: @Mohammad See that's where the problem is,the way you are assigning the datacontext.See my updated answer