# Binding a control to color in Win8 app store

Tags: binding, windows-8

I have a LayoutAwarePage with a property of type Color - "MyColor".
I added a simple control to the page like a Rectangle or a TextBox, and bounded the background of the control to MyColor.
I set MyColor to black, white, red etc' - none of this works. The controls remain black no matter what I did. How to solve this?

I followed your advice and it worked, thanks! I also tried to add the next style to the page:

```
<Grid.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Style TargetType="a:MyTextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding TextBlockBackgroundColor}"></Setter>
                   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding TextBlockBorderColor}"></Setter>
                   <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"></Setter>
                   <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False"></Setter>
                   <Setter  Property="BorderBrush" Value="3" ></Setter>
               </Style>
           </ResourceDictionary>
      </Grid.Resources>
```

And now I can't see the controls of the type MyTextBlock...

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind `Fill` property of `Rectangle` with `SolidColorBrush` rather than `Color`. See the below code.

viewModel.cs

```
public class viewModel
{
    public Color color { get; set; }
    public viewModel(Color _color)
    {
        color = _color;
    }
    public SolidColorBrush MyColor
    {
        get
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(color);
        }
    }
}
```

BlankPage1.xaml.cs

```
public BlankPage1()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new viewModel(Colors.Red);
}
```

XAML

```
<Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="{Binding MyColor}" />
```

Comment: Ok. But why do I have to do this? Why can't I use Color and must use SolidColorBrush?

Comment: Because `Fill`, `Background`, `Foreground`, `Stroke` properties are type of `SolidColorBrush`, not `Color`.

Comment: Native `TextBlock` don't have `Background` & `BorderBrush` property. Can you please share code of `MyTextBlock` ?

Comment: Do you want to do like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084091/binding-style-setter-to-a-public-property) ?

Comment: I derived from TextBox and called it MyTextBlock... :)

Comment: No, i want to understand why MyTextBlock is not shown and fix this problem. Can you please help me with that?