# WPF dynamically add controls and Binding issue

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, telerik

I have two questions:

1. Why `Color` binding doesn't work. Could you please provide proper way of setting binding to manage colors dynamically?
2. Now my `SplineAreaSeries` are static and initialized in XAML. If I want to add 10 more series, what is the best and more elegant way of doing that?

XAML:

```
    <telerik:RadCartesianChart x:Name="xRevChart">
        <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Grid>
            <telerik:CartesianChartGrid MajorLinesVisibility="XY" MajorXLineDashArray="10.5"
                                        MajorXLinesRenderMode="All"/>
        </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Grid>
        <telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
            <telerik:LinearAxis></telerik:LinearAxis>
        </telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
        <telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
            <telerik:CategoricalAxis></telerik:CategoricalAxis>
        </telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
        <telerik:SplineAreaSeries Name="xSplineArea1" CategoryBinding="XValue" ValueBinding="YValue">
            <telerik:SplineAreaSeries.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}"/>
            </telerik:SplineAreaSeries.Fill>
        </telerik:SplineAreaSeries>
        <telerik:SplineAreaSeries Name="xSplineArea2" CategoryBinding="XValue" ValueBinding="YValue">
            <telerik:SplineAreaSeries.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}"/>
            </telerik:SplineAreaSeries.Fill>
        </telerik:SplineAreaSeries>
    </telerik:RadCartesianChart>
```

CODE:

```
public class ChartDataClass
{
    public double XValue { get; set; }
    public double YValue { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }  
}

        List<ChartDataClass> list1 = new List<ChartDataClass>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            ChartDataClass c = new ChartDataClass();
            c.XValue = i;
            c.YValue = rand.NextDouble() * 100;
            c.Color = Colors.Blue;
            list1.Add(c);
        }

        xRevChart.Series[1].ItemsSource = list1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a converter to return what you need on binding.

It's a dupe question I think: [How do I convert a Color to a Brush in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309709/how-do-i-convert-a-color-to-a-brush-in-xaml)

Comment: As I can understood `<SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding YourColorProperty}" />` works the same principle as a converter but already declared in XAML, so I think this is not a convert issue. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!