# Bind Drawing.Color from settings with Style in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, settings, bind

How to bind Color *Bkg* (System.Drawing.Color), defined in settings, with Style in XAML?

*xmlns:props="clr-namespace:App.Properties"*

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}" x:Key="_itemStyle">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Bkg, Source={x:Static props:Settings.Default}}"/>
```

Background property is of type System.Windows.Media.Color, so it needs to be somehow converted?

Comment: Why not simply create a setting of type `System.Windows.Media.Color`? Just click `Browse...` in the Settings Type combobox and select PresentationCore -> System.Windows.Media -> Color.

Comment: Hmm, nice. But how to define transparent color?

Comment: @PatrikPolakovic if any ans solve your problem the you can mark it right ..

Comment: @PatrikPolakovic Just set the first byte according to the desired opacity, or alpha value. The structure of the color string is #AARRGGBB, hence e.g. #7FFF0000 is semi-transparent red. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.aspx) also.

Comment: In addition to what dkozl has answered, you may also directly create a setting of type `System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush`.

Comment: @PatrikPolakovic i think that you got your ans..so whichever solved your problem you can atleast mark that right..

Comment: Thank you for your help. Problem solved using @dkozl solution :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Panel.Background`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.background.aspx) property is of a `System.Windows.Media.Brush` type and not `System.Windows.Media.Color` therefore you need to convert it into `SolidColorBrush`. Below you can find both case scenarios:

**Setting is of `System.Windows.Media.Color` type**

```
<Setter Property="Background">
   <Setter.Value>
      <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Source={x:Static props:Settings.Default}, Path=Bkg}"/>
   </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

**Setting is of `System.Drawing.Color` type**: for this you need custom `IValueConverter` to convert it into `SolidColorBrush`:

```
public class ColorToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
      var dc = (System.Drawing.Color)value;
      return new SolidColorBrush(new Color { A = dc.A, R = dc.R, G = dc.G, B = dc.B });
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

which you define in your resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ColorToBrushConverter x:Key="ColorToBrushConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

and you can use it like this:

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static props:Settings.Default}, Path=Bkg, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, I used System.Windows.Media.Color variant.

Answer (score 0):

As you would know that background property is of solidbrush type so its value can be set or get only with some solidbrush typw property . so what you can do is make a solidbrush type property in place of color like this..in your setting class.
and now every thing just work fine..

```
 static SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

    public static SolidColorBrush colorBrush
    {
        get
        {
            return brush;
        }
    }
```

if you dont want to do that then you have to use value converter ..for that you can follow

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309709/how-do-i-convert-a-color-to-a-brush-in-xaml)..hope it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a setting of type `System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush`.

Select `Browse...` from the **Type** ComboBox of the new setting, then select `PresentationCore` -> `System.Windows.Media` -> `SolidColorBrush`.

You may now directly use that setting as you already did:

```
<Setter Property="Background"
        Value="{Binding Path=Bkg, Source={x:Static props:Settings.Default}}"/>
```