# How to use DoubleAnimation for changing "Tint"?

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm used to cocos2d to apply tint animation of an object and I was hoping to find the same in wpf since Opacity is very similar between cocos2d and wpf as shown below:

```
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                image.BeginInit();
                image.UriSource = new Uri(LongResourcesPath + item.ImageFile);
                image.EndInit();
                imgProfile.Source = image;
                imgProfile.Opacity = 0;

                DoubleAnimation anin = new DoubleAnimation();
                anin.From = 0;
                anin.To = 1;
                anin.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));

                imgProfile.BeginAnimation(Image.OpacityProperty, anin);
```

How can I change the code to change tint from a 100% white to 0 (image normal tint)

thanks

Comment: I came up with a solution for tinting in WPF: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28247011/1218281