# MVVM ViewModel and type of property (PresentationCore.dll )

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, binding

**Can we use classes from the assemblies targeted for UI /UI framework in my ViewModel?**

Today I had a discussion over a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35072809/c-sharp-wpf-mvvm-if-statements/35077504?noredirect=1#comment57889249_35077504) where one person is very persistent about that classes from PresentationCore.dll can't be used in a ViewModel.(seems like he has not used ICommand ever) But is that right?

As my understanding MVVM only a pattern for decoupling of View & ViewModel? it doesn't say anything about what type of classes I can use in a ViewModel as long as they don't create a view(**ViewModel has no direct reference to the view or any knowledge about the view's specific implementation or type**).

Please don't answer as what is a good practice or not, I just want to be clear about MVVM.

Comment: From an architectural standpoint it doesn't matter at all in which assembly the types are defined that you use in your view model. There are in fact some types from PresentationCore that are often found in view models, like Geometry, Color, Brush, BitmapSource, etc. However, they all have in common that they aren't Visuals.

Comment: @Clemens I agree. but what if I use some property that is visual and not creating a view(I just want to use a function or say enum of that class)?

Comment: I've read discussion from linked question. @Tseng just doesn't understand, what decoupling view from view model is, and looks a little fanatic. Anyway, your understanding is right.

Comment: @KyloRen Just do it!

Comment: @Clemens OK. I've the same understanding too.

Comment: You can do whatever you want.  If it makes sense, and makes your job easier and doesn't hurt the product, then why not do it?  Also, you're not Kylo Ren.  Imposter.

Comment: @Will yeah sure I can. but concern was to actuaaly know the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes MVVM looks like religion with its own trends. :)

Here are themes for holy wars between members of MVVM sects:

- view first vs view model first;
- do/don't expose `PresentationFramework`/`WindowsBase` types from view models;
- do/don't expose model through your view model, and bind view directly to model;
- converters vs view model properties;
- aggregate model in view model / map model data to view model;
- use event aggregators / use services.

The most dangerous are "pure MVVM" fanatics. Nobody exactly knows, what "pure MVVM" is, but they are ready to burn you, if you're violating their belief.

MVVM just wants you to keep view *logic* separately from view model *logic*.
**That's all**.

The list from above is just a set of *approaches*, not dogmata. And, actually, all of them fit MVVM. To use or not to use is just a matter of convenience and current project architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the below links:

[The MVVM Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/hh848246.aspx)

[MVVM Basics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msgulfcommunity/archive/2013/03/13/understanding_2d00_the_2d00_basics_2d00_of_2d00_mvvm_2d00_design_2d00_pattern.aspx)

There is no such limitations of property types. This pattern Only **decoupling** of View and Model by using ViewModel layer.

Answer (score -1):

Simple example from the previous question/answer: `SolidColorBrush`.

This type is declared in two different assemblies: Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract (UWP app) and PresencationCore.dll (WPF). They both different type, with different namespaces and different identities (Identity of a type is coupled to it's assembly.

`TypeA` assembly A is different than TypeA from assemblyB. You can't pass `AssemblyA.TypeA` to an object expecting `AssemblyB.TypeA`

Why does it matter?

Take that ViewModel as example

```
// WPF namespace
using System.Windows.Media;

public class ExampleViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public SolidColorBrush Color { get; set; }
}
```

When you use this in WPF, all is fine and working. Now you want make an UWP App and this won't work. UWP do not know `System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush` from PresentationCore.dll. It only knows about `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush` from Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.dll, even if they have same methods, same parameters and even same implementation, they are different.

Even worse, because your ViewModel requires PresentationCore.dll, it is necessarily tied to .NET 3.x or 4.x, whereas UWP is based on WinRT/Core Framework.

This is a tight coupling. Now assume you also want to use Xamarin (Crossplatform .NET framework based on mono) and that `SolidColorBrush` is in i.e. Xamarin.Forms.dll (I haven't used Xamarin and I don't for sure it even has a type of such name).

How about Linux/Mono version? There is no WPF on mono. Console application? They don't even use UI elements.

Then you can't bind it and you end up duplicating your ViewModels and duplicate your presentation logic etc.

With your "MVVM" approach, you increased testability, but have not archived reusability and decoupling.

There are no specification which tell you: "This must be done so and so.". MVVM is no specification, it is a (architectural) pattern.

For the sake about the aboves example, if you need determine color you use a non-ui specific type (`string`, `Color`, or your own implementation of a color class/struct).

For the views, you implement an `IValueConverter´ (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3309904/455493) for example).

Now you have beautiful, decoupled code which you can reuse and each UI platform can handle colors in their own way.

And it's as easy as directly returning `SolidColorBrush` at the cost of a few lines of code. And best of it, you can reuse `ColorToSolidColorBrushValueConverter` everywhere and in every of the applications you create. `ColorToSolidColorBrushValueConverter` do not depend on your specific application and your application/view model don't depend on it.

It's not hard to write good code, you just have to try it ;)

Comment: Normally, you won't / can't share source code between WPF and UWP apps without conditional compilation. Moreover, not every view model will be used as cross-platform. Hence, if I write WPF app, I can use reference to PresentationFramework and `System.Windows.Media`. If I write something cross-platform, I'll either use some conditional compilation, or I'll put platform-specific code elsewhere. Anyway, it depends on what project is being written.

Comment: @Tseng why do you put MVVM in the center and talk round and round. The question was very simple that was their any coupling? There can be million different approached to design better than MVVM or altering MVVM, but that is not the scope here.

Comment: It's not like it's hard to implement a simple `IValueConverter` and remove the `SolidColorBrush` reference. For exact the same reason there is an out-of-the-box converter for bool to visibility (as visibility only has a meaning to WPF) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Because the question was tagged MVVM and not just WPF. For pure WPF applications, your answer was okay (even the one before you edited it). But when someone asks a question and tags it MVVM, he expects MVVM compliant answers. Rather than accepting that, you just cause fuzz about it unable to accept answers from people with more experience in this field. And instead of just learning how to apply MVVM properly, you just keep talking

Comment: @Tseng there you go again. Not answering what I asked. I've now seen your thought process so there is no point listening to you anymore. you better now come up with some good blogs/articles about it. I'll be more than happy if I learn something about it. and just for your sake the question is "how was there any coupling that violates the MVVM?"