# WPF ResourceDictionary and Binding

Tags: css, wpf, resourcedictionary

I#m a beginner with WPF. I want to make the same like css/sass. I want to reuse some definitions.

Here I want to reuse a color definition in an element (e.g. button). If I use binding with "staticresource", I get the following exception when running:

*"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: "#FF8FA2AC" ist kein gültiger Wert für die Eigenschaft "Background".*"

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    >

    <Color x:Key="cyan3">#007ca9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="mangenta2">#a8005c</Color>
    <Color x:Key="wintergrey1">#e6ecf0</Color>
    <Color x:Key="wintergrey2">#c3ced5</Color>
    <Color x:Key="wintergrey3">#8fa2ac</Color>
    <Color x:Key="wintergrey4">#506671</Color>
    <Color x:Key="white">#FFFFFF</Color>
    <Color x:Key="antrazit">#333333</Color>

    <!-- Base style for button -->
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="btnStandard">
        <!--Setter Property="Background" Value="#8fa2ac"/-->
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource wintergrey3}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

How can I use predefined definitions in other elements? Or what is wrong. I want do define 4 different button styles "Standard", "IsFocused", "IsDisabled" and "IsHero (background=mangenta2".

Comment: `Background` is not a color, it is a `Brush`. declare brushes in resources (e.g. SolidColorBrush) and reuse them in your styles and views; btw, `<Setter Property="Background" Value="#8fa2ac">` creates a Brush from "#8fa2ac" hex code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a Color to a Brush in XAML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309709/how-do-i-convert-a-color-to-a-brush-in-xaml)

Comment: I have change `<Color x:Key="cyan3">#007ca9</Color>` to this `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="cyan3">#007ca9</SolidColorBrush>`

Answer (score 0):

You should set the Background property to a [Brush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush(v=vs.110).aspx). If you set it to a `SolidColorBrush` you can then set the Color property of this one to your Color resource like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="btnStandard">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource wintergrey3}" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
</Style>
```