# Change background color between ListBoxItems

Tags: wpf, background, listbox

This is part of my window: [MyListBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sP8g8.png).
I would like the space between the items to be green as well (if the upper and lower item is green) but I don't know how to change it.

This is my XAML code (tried to put the background colour in the StackPanel but nothing changed):

```
<ListBox Background="LightCyan" Name="MondayListBox">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Background="{Binding backgroundColor}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time, StringFormat={}{0:hh}:{0:mm}}" Background="{Binding BackgroundColor}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Any suggestion would be very appreciated.

EDIT:
I setted the `backgorundColor` to be a `Brush`and initialized it with `Brushes.LightCyan` but I still have the white spaces between the items.

Comment: Have you tried checking the Margin of the StackPanels?

Comment: What do you mean? I tried  <StackPanel Margin="{Binding BackgroundColor}"> but nothing changes...

Answer (score 0):

Where is `backgroundColor` coming from? Are you sure that it's a `Brush` object, as required for `Control.Background`, rather than just a `Color` value?

You can use a `ValueConverter` class, such as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3309904/967885) to convert from one to the other.

Comment: That is just a Color, I didn't know it had to be a Brush, Thank you very much!