# Setting a different property in XAML gridview using the DisplayMemberBinding

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm trying to create a grid view with 3 columns, these are taken from a struct:

```
    public struct ColorAttribute
    {
        public Color Color { get; set; }

        public string TextValue { get; set; }

        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
```

And then I want to build a the table like so:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ColorAttributes}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Color" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Color}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Color Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TextValue}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Count" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Count}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

The part I'm not sure about though, is that for the first column, I want to just display a little box of the color, but I'm not sure how to bind the DisplayMemberBinding to something else like the foreground. Currently it just shows as the RGB value again.

Comment: Simply customize cell template of corresponding column and [bind color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3309709/1997232) to background.

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly that issue is talking about setting a column to a preset colour. I'm asking how to set the colour per cell based on the value inside the struct.

Comment: Converting it a brush isn't the issue, it's how to get the display member binding and use that as a color input for the foreground.

Comment: Just bind to `Color`. You can remove `DisplayMemberBinding` from that column definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define template for the cell and inside the `DataTemplate` bind `Background` or `Foreground` to `Color` in your view model. You have to create a converter to convert `Color` to `Brush`.

```
<Windows.Resources>
    <local:ColorToBrushConverter x:Key="ColorToBrushConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
...
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ColorAttributes}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Color" Width="120">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Border Margin="0,0,5,0" Width="20" 
                             Background="{Binding Color, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Color}" 
                             Foreground="{Binding Color, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}"/>
                        </StackPanel>                                
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Color Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TextValue}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Count" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Count}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

[Color to brush converter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3309709/1997232)

[image]