# C# Brush to string

Tags: c#, string, brush

I search a way to save the color of a brush as a string.
For example I have a Brush which has the color red.
Now I want to write "red" in a textbox.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Which `Brush` class do you mean exactly? From what namespace?

Comment: Possible solution? http://stackoverflow.com/q/372693/122005

Comment: I mean the Brush class under System.Windows.Media.Brush

Comment: If you're using a `SolidColorBrush` this is easy - try `brush.Color.ToString()`, but I think this might give an RGB representation rather than a name like 'red'.

Comment: @chridam: He wants string => Brush, I want Brush => string

Comment: Do you have some ideas on how specific the color should be?  i.e. converting `#FF0000` and `#DC143C` both look very close to "red" but are very different colors.  Most `ToString(`) representations will try to preserve the detail...  If you want a generic color name, you'll probably have to do the work yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Brush` was created using a `Color` from `System.Drawing.Color`, then you can use the `Color`'s [`Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.name.aspx) property.

Otherwise, you could just try to look up the color using reflection

```
// hack
var b = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 235, 205));
var colorname = (from p in typeof(System.Drawing.Color).GetProperties()
                 where p.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(System.Drawing.Color))
                 let value = (System.Drawing.Color)p.GetValue(null, null)
                 where value.R == b.Color.R &&
                       value.G == b.Color.G &&
                       value.B == b.Color.B &&
                       value.A == b.Color.A
                 select p.Name).DefaultIfEmpty("unknown").First();

// colorname == "BlanchedAlmond"
```

or create a mapping yourself (and look the color up via a `Dictionary`), probably using [one](http://gucky.uni-muenster.de/cgi-bin/rgbtab-en) of many color tables around.

**Edit:**

You wrote a comment saying you use `System.Windows.Media.Color`, but you could still use `System.Drawing.Color` to look up the name of the color.

```
var b = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 235, 205);
var colorname = (from p in typeof(System.Drawing.Color).GetProperties()
                 where p.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(System.Drawing.Color))
                 let value = (System.Drawing.Color)p.GetValue(null, null)
                 where value.R == b.R &&
                       value.G == b.G &&
                       value.B == b.B &&
                       value.A == b.A
                 select p.Name).DefaultIfEmpty("unknown").First();
```

Comment: Thanks, I have changed to System.Drawing.Color and now I become with .Name the right name of the color. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What type of brush is this? If its drawing namespace, then brush is an abstract class.! For SolidBrush, do:

brush.Color.ToString()

Otherwise, get the color property and use ToString() method to convert color to its string representation.

Comment: I mean the Brush class under System.Windows.Media.Brush. When I make in this class .toString will I become the number of the color, for example: #FF0000FF

Answer (score 0):

Basically I'll post what was already answered.

```
string color = textBox1.Text;

// best, using Color's static method
Color red1 = Color.FromName(color);

// using a ColorConverter
TypeConverter tc1 = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Color)); // ..or..
TypeConverter tc2 = new ColorConverter();
Color red2 = (Color)tc.ConvertFromString(color);

// using Reflection on Color or Brush
Color red3 = (Color)typeof(Color).GetProperty(color).GetValue(null, null);

// in WPF you can use a BrushConverter
SolidColorBrush redBrush = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(color);
```

Original answer: [Convert string to Brushes/Brush color name in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372693/convert-string-to-brushes-brush-color-name-in-c-sharp)

Comment: the OP wants is other way round

Comment: this creates a brush from a string, not a name from the brush.

Comment: I see. My bad. .toString() then.

Answer (score 0):

I had a object of System.Drawing.Brush and the color information is not accessible. It couldn't be case to type color either. It is possible to cast this to SolidBrush where the color information is available. I was able to cast my `Brush color` object to a SolidBrush and then pull the name from the color this way.

```
((SolidBrush)color).Color.Name
```