# How to convert System.Drawing.Brush to string

Tags: c#

I cannot find any correct solution for this

```
string colorName = ...converting... Brushes.Brown;

So colorName  should have 'Brown'
```

Is it possible?

Comment: About the only way I can think to do this is using reflection to loop through all the static properties of the `System.Drawing.Brushes` class and test for equality between the value of each property and the brush whose name you're trying to find.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842003/c-sharp-brush-to-string

Comment: What about `nameof(Brushes.Brown)`?

Comment: SolidBrush b = Brushes.AliceBlue as SolidBrush;
b.Color.Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I found a way to do it.

```
public string GetColorName(Brush brush)
        {
            string name = "Unknown";
            Color c = new Pen(brush).Color;

            foreach (KnownColor kc in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)))
            {
                Color known = Color.FromKnownColor(kc);
                if (c.ToArgb() == known.ToArgb())
                {
                    name = known.Name;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return name;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the desired result, you can use:

```
string colorName = nameof(Brushes.Brown);
```

Now `colorName` should have the value `'Brown'`.

Comment: this produces "color"  and not the word "Brown"