# How do i get the color from Rectangle in fill property?

Tags: wpf, colors, fill, rectangles, converters

I know how to set fill from WPF control.

```
Rectangle a = new Rectangle()
a.Fill = Brushes.Red;
```

but i can't get the color.

i want code like this.

```
string color = a.Fill; // Red
var color2 = a.Fill(T); // Brushes.Red
var color3 = a.Fill; // other object
```

Comment: `var color = (a.Fill as SolidColorBrush)?.Color;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you want to get the name of the color in your  `Rectangle.Fill` Property as string (the way you would type it in xaml)?

I have found a solution for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842003/c-sharp-brush-to-string)

in your code it should look like this:

```
      SolidColorBrush brush = (SolidColorBrush)a.Fill;
  Color c = brush.Color;
  var colorname = (from p in typeof(System.Drawing.Color).GetProperties()
                   where p.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(System.Drawing.Color))
                   let value = (System.Drawing.Color)p.GetValue(null, null)
                   where value.R == c.R &&
                         value.G == c.G &&
                         value.B == c.B &&
                         value.A == c.A
                   select p.Name).DefaultIfEmpty("unknown").First();
```

For my Rectangle `<Rectangle Name="a" Fill="Aqua"></Rectangle>` the String will return "Aqua".

Comment: Thank you @Azzarrel :) i choose a your answer.