# Casting a string to a Brush object

Tags: c#, brush

I currently have some global variables like this (the global part isn't really relevant):

```
public Brush backgroundColor;
public Brush textColor;
public double timeOffset;
public double dateOffset;
public string title;
public bool showTitle;
public bool showText;
```

I declare a new `List<string>` to store said variables using this:

```
List<string> x = new List<string>();
x.Add(backgroundColor);
x.Add(textColor);
x.Add(timeOffset.ToString());
x.Add(dateOffset.ToString());
x.Add(title);
x.Add(showTitle.ToString());
x.Add(showText.ToString());
```

Noticeably, I'm only temporarily storing these strings into my list. I will be using them later on as objects. If I wanted to convert my `strings` from this list to types like `bool` or `double`, I can simply us `Convert.ToDouble()` or `Convert.ToBoolean()`, however, I am unable to find anything that could do so for a `Brush` object.

My `Brush` object is used like this: `Brushes.Black` ([Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushes.black%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) MSDN). I've looked at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372693/convert-string-to-brushes-brush-color-name-in-c-sharp), but the ways they input are either in RGB or Hexadecimal, which isn't what I need.

EDIT: If there is no way, or you can suggest better ways to use this, please let me know. Why I need a `Brushes.XXXX` is because I am drawing images onto `bitmap` objects.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing "colors" as brushes. Store them as colors.. then build a brush based on them. You simply cannot create a single brush with the properties of two other brushes...

Comment: How do you even use that list? Do you "remember" what the type of the item in each index is?

Comment: Why store them as strings anyway? Create a class as a wrapper or at least store them in a list of `object`, this will make the casting really a lot easier.

Comment: @DaveZych Yes. It's a list of only seven objects.
@SimonWhitehead Why I am doing it this way is basically because I have a method that takes an input for `Brush`, like this: `public void manualBackgroundColor(Brush backgroundColor)` which draws things onto a `graphics` object.

Comment: @Abbas Like this? `List<object> settings = new List<object>()`?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage `It's a list of only seven objects` - Yes, and you're _only_ doing it wrong.

Comment: @DaveZych No need to be snarky.. I'm only here to learn. What do you suggest?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Review my answer.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage yes like that. But a more correct way is to create a class holding the properties and then you can pass a single instance of the class around to do stuff. No ugly casting needed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the properties in a list, I suggest you use `List<object>`. Since all classes in .NET derive from the `object` class, casting will be a lot more logic than casting a string to an object. Since you're using a list of objects, you don't need a class anymore to hold the properties. Also, you can use the object initializer to create the list instead of calling the `Add()` method every time. The assignment of the list will look like:

```
List<object> properties = new List<object>
{
    backgroundColor,
    textColor,
    timeOffset,
    dateOffset,
    title,
    showTitle,
    showText
};
```

And now you can pass this list to your method, like this:

```
YourListExpectingMethod(properties);
```

In the method you'll have to provide some logic to determine to which type to cast the object!

More reading:

- *Object Initializers*

  - [**Object and Collection Initializers**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)
  - [**How to: Initialize Objects by Using an Object Initializer**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx)
- *Casting*

  - [**Casting and Type Conversions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)
  - [**How to: Safely Cast by Using as and is Operators**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488006.aspx)
  - [**Direct casting vs 'as' operator?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator)

Comment: Hey Abbas - if I wanted to access `backgroundColor` of `properties`, do I simply do so with `properties.backgroundColor`? Do I need to specify getters or setters below? Thanks!

Comment: No, they are in the list. So you access them through an indexer, like this: `Brush backgroundColor = (Brush)properties[0];`. Getters and setters are for properties and properties belong to classes. The 'properties' in the list are just items from that list.

Answer (score 3):

I would advise creating a class to hold all of this information:

```
public class MyDrawingInfo
{
    public Brush BackgroundColor;
    public Brush TextColor;
    public double TimeOffset;
    public double DateOffset;
    public string Title;
    public bool ShowTitle;
    public bool ShowText;
}
```

Now you can instantiate a class with this info, pass it around and not have to perform some crazy casting everywhere.

EDIT: To use this class, first instantiate it:

```
MyDrawingInfo mdi = new MyDrawingInfo();
mdi.BackgroundColor = Brushes.Black;
//etc
```

Then, when calling another method, pass the property you need:

```
ManualBackgroundColor(mdi.BackgroundColor)
```

Note: I updated the names of the properties and your method name. It is standard in C# to have your property and method names be [Pascal Case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Hey Dave. How would I use this, for example, pass `backgroundColor` to the input of a method that's outside of this class?

Comment: Cool, cool. Hey, so one more question. I need to have my seven variables parsed in through a list no matter what, since that's the design of the settings component (which is what houses the variables above). It must be accessed through 0-6th index. How do I store those into the global vars of the `MyDrawingInfo` class? Someone above suggested using `List<object>`

Comment: I was the one who proposed using this, check my answer for a more detailed explanation. :)