# How do I prevent memory leak from SolidColorBrush object?

Tags: c#, wpf, idisposable, solidcolorbrush

There's no option to dispose SolidColorBrush.

How do I prevent memory leak from SolidColorBrush object?

I can't even use 'using' as SolidColorBrush doesn't implement IDisposable Interface.

Comment: Why do you need to dispose it? Does it reference any unmanaged memory?

Comment: _prevent_ or create. It could create memory fragmentation, but the memory used by that SolidColorBrush will be freed by the garbage collector and probably  reused for the next solidcolorbrush. But like Maarten says. use the predefined brushes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't create new `SolidColorBrush` instances.

Use the [predefined brushes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushes(v=vs.110).aspx) in `System.Windows.Media.Brushes`.

Otherwise, create a single instance, and re-use that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my experience.

If I use below code there is a huge memory leak while running it couple hundred thousand times.

```
SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush( helper.ConvertValueToColorCanvas(colorValue, slider.Value));
mainCanvas.rects.Add(new MyCanvas.MyRect() { Brush = brush, Rect = new Rect(p0X + leftMargin + width, p0Y + height, (p2X - p0X), (p2Y - p0Y)) });
```

But if I use below code, the leak become partially stop.

```
mainCanvas.rects.Add(new MyCanvas.MyRect() { Brush = new SolidColorBrush( helper.ConvertValueToColorCanvas(colorValue, slider.Value)), Rect = new Rect(p0X + leftMargin + width, p0Y + height, (p2X - p0X), (p2Y - p0Y)) });
```

So instead of creating new solidbrush variable, if you use it just directly in constructor, it worked for me.